# File doesn't upload to localhost via PHP

Tags: php, html

I cannot upload file to localhost using PHP. I have created simple html form and php script. However I get these error messages.

'import.html'

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="import.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p>
                <label for="file">Choose import.xml</label><br/>
                <input type="file" name="import" id="import" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
        </form>
    <body>
</html>
```

'import.php'

```
<?php
    if ($_FILES["import"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["import"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["import"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["import"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["import"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["import"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["import"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["import"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["import"]["tmp_name"],
            "upload/" . $_FILES["import"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["import"]["name"];
        }
    }

?>
```

Error messages:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/import.xml)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\teecom\admin\import.php on line 20
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to
>   move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpD02C.tmp' to 'upload/import.xml' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\teecom\admin\import.php on line 20 Stored in:
>   upload/import.xml

Comment: So it tells you what the problem is. Are you disputing that the directory exists and is writable?

Comment: I would guess that (a) your web server does not have write permissions in the upload directory, or (b) you need to use an absolute path for the uploads directory instead of `"upload/"`

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\teecom\admin\upload\ directory exists??

Comment: Temporary directory is: C:\Windows\Temp\phpD02C.tmp.

However, I think apache does not have permission to read/write to this directory. I cannot find where I can change that directory.

Comment: Well, C:\xampp\htdocs\teecom\admin\upload\ exists. So does C:\windows\temp\. However, I think the problem is with temporary directory C:\windows\temp\. I don't think I have permission to this directory. Thats why I wanna change it. I have changed all php.ini files I can find. But it still uploads to this directory

Comment: Even you give reasons why you think it should work, PHP still tells you that it does not work. Can you imagine additional things that are blocking access? Which kind of information are you missing to understand the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to your localhost directories you can try this:

```php
if (!file_exists("teecom/upload"))
{
    mkdir("teecom/upload", 0777, true);
}
if (file_exists("teecom/upload/" . $_FILES["import"]["name"]))
{
    echo $_FILES["import"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}
else
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["import"]["tmp_name"],
    "teecom/upload/" . $_FILES["import"]["name"]);
    echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["import"]["name"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using Windows.

I'd change the destination path from a relative to an absolute path if possible. For example:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["import"]["tmp_name"],
            "C:/upload/" . $_FILES["import"]["name"]);
```

Or try the path:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/upload/' . $_FILES['import']['name']
```

Also try creating that C:\upload\ or C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\ directory first before trying to upload to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your file was clearly not uploaded to the temporary folder from which the `move_uploaded_file` function is supposed to move it. There is plenty of reasons why that might happen the most frequent one being that you don't have write permissions to the temporary folder PHP is using.

Comment: @Waygood, good point! But I cannot find the file in temporary folder.

Comment: @holdoc, I changed php.ini file so that temporary folder would be something I have permission to. But, error messages still point to C:\windows\temp\ directory

Comment: check file_uploads, safe mode, max post size and upload_max_filesize too. I found working on windows previously (linux now) that I sometime had to restart the pc as apache restart didn't always work.

Comment: One more thing - do not try to look for the temporary upload files in the temp folder because you won't find them. All temporary upload files are removed after the request has been completed.

Comment: @holodoc You're right! Right now I am testing this upload issue on localhost. If I quickly switch from browser to file manager, the file appears in the uploaded files directory (also with correct filesize), but after a second, when the script is finished, it's removed. Yes the whole problem is only not existing target directory.

Comment: @Stano, you are right. It appears that I didn't have permission to upload directory, not temporary directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but for people who have this problem in the future, all I did for my localhost (wamp) is click the server icon, go to PHP, PHP Settings, and select File Uploads.

This worked for me.

Comment: also check `php.ini` for `upload_max_filesize = 2M` if you are attempting to upload a large file