# error uploading image to directory

Tags: php, upload

I keep on getting these warnings when i try to upload images to my directory:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(localhost/school/photo/IMG_3036.PNG):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\school\Pages\upload.php on line 20
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\xampp\tmp\phpDE6A.tmp' to 'localhost/school/photo/IMG_3036.PNG' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\school\Pages\upload.php on line 20

CODE:

```
 <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="upload" /> &nbsp; <input type="submit" name="btn_upload" value="UPLOAD" />
 </form> 
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['btn_upload']))
{
$filetmp = $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];
$filename = $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
$filetype = $_FILES["upload"]["type"];
$filepath = "localhost/school/photo/".$filename; 
 move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath); //LINE 20

$con = mysqli_connect ("localhost" , "web" , "" , "imagestore") or die ("could not connect"); 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO upload_img (img_name,img_path,img_type) VALUES ('$filename','$filepath','$filetype')";

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("error");

} 

 ?>
```

HERES my directory,

```
c:xammp\htdocs\school\photo
```

Comment: Do you have [file uploads enabled in your PHP ini file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.file-uploads)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [File doesn't upload to localhost via PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435132/file-doesnt-upload-to-localhost-via-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`move_uploaded_file` requires a filesystem path, not a `url` path, as the destination. you are passing a url path. assuming you have permission to write to the folder, setting a correct `$filepath` should work:

`$filepath = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\school\\photo\\".$filename;`

since that is the actual path on your computer to the photos directory.